# What are css and javaScript files called in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When coding a html webpage, what is the official name for css and javascript files that are added to the html code?

For example, if I have some html code that requires a `link href` for `jquery-ui.css` and a `script` for `jquery.js`, what are these files officially called?

Is the correct jargon a library or libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Scripts and stylesheets. Alternatively, JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: If it's important that they're linked in and not in the `.html` file then the only important word is _external_

Comment: This question made me realize how many different terms we have for the same things. *Script, stylesheet, static asset, library, document, module.* Many could be interchanged in several contexts.

Comment: *External* stylesheet/CSS/javascript/JS/script.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, CSS files are called stylesheets, and Javascript files are called scripts. Javascript and CSS that other javascript relies on to run (for instance the js library jQuery, or the js/css library Bootstrap) is called a library.

A more general word, that would include stylesheets, scripts, images, and basically everything else, would be "assets".

Answer (score 1):

As minitech commented, external JavaScript and CSS are called scripts and stylesheets, respectively.

Libraries are collections of pre-written code often used as a framework for building applications, and include things like jQuery UI. In your example, the file `jquery-ui.css` is a stylesheet because it is an external file of CSS, and it is also a library because it's a front-end framework.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we called it static content (In your case but need not be alway) or "asset" of the web page but to be more specific -

External Javascript and external style sheet (CSS) linked to the HTML page.

Comment: Stylesheets and scripts, while most often static, do not always need to be.

Comment: Yes! I agree . Just talking about the jQuery case that he pointed out. But yes accepted.